# Browse a Apache Server from Nautilus

Tags: server, apache2, nautilus

This is a public server. I can browse it from any web-browser without any user-name or password. Can I have a ShortCut in File-browser (like Nautilus, Dolphin etc) so that I can browse it File-Browser?

[image]

Comment: No, because Nautilus is a file browser, and what you carelessly called "any browser" is most likely a web browser. Not the same.

Comment: If the directory is also served by FTP, however...

Comment: @mikewhatever Sorry it was a typo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot point a Nautilus shortcut here.

What you have on your web page is Apache's automatic display of a directory listing because it can't reach or doesn't have an index page.  The listing you see is only able to be viewed in a *web browser* like a Chrome or Firefox, not a filesystem browser like Nautilus.

This is all handled by internal file listing of Apache checking the file system on the remote server and then presenting that information as a web page.  It is not a network drive or anything you can connect Nautilus to; it's simply Apache's listing of the directory and not something Nautilus can connect to.